# How to fix with KeyError: q[minKey]? Run time error on python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently doing my school assignment which needs to be submitted to ***Automarker*** to test the code.

The question I'm stuck has to pass 5 different tasks and each task contains different input which is **not given**.

The only input is given is the sample input which shows below.

I keep getting the result of **"KeyError: del q[min_Key]"** and the status show **"RunTimeError"**.

I don't understand how does it occurs?

And how to fix this error correctly?

```py
from math import sqrt
import math

def getP(numV, ver, e):
    d = -1
    q = {0:0.0}
    while bool(q):
        minNum = 9999.0
        min_Key = len(q) - 1
        for k in q.keys():
            if minNum > q[k]:
                minNum = q[k]
                min_Key = k
        if numV-1 == min_Key:
            d = minNum
            break
        del q[min_Key]
        for v in e[min_Key].keys():
            if v not in q:
                q[v] = minNum+e[min_Key][v]
            else:
                if q[v] > minNum+e[min_Key][v]:
                    q[v] = minNum+e[min_Key][v]

    return (d)


while True:
    try:
        user_input = input().split(',')
        size = len(user_input)
        n = user_input[0]
        ver = {}
        numV = 0
        for i in range(1, size):
            if i % 2 == 1:
                ver[numV] = (float(user_input[i]), float(user_input[i+1]))
                numV = numV + 1
        e = {}
        for u in ver.keys():
            e[u] = {}
            for v in ver.keys():
                if u != v:
                    dist1 = (ver[u][1] - ver[v][1])*(ver[u][1] - ver[v][1])
                    dist2 = (ver[u][0] - ver[v][0])*(ver[u][0] - ver[v][0])
                    dist = dist1 + dist2
                    if dist <= 10000.0:
                        dist = sqrt(dist)
                        e[u][v] = dist

        d = getP(numV, ver, e)
        if d == -1:
            print(d)
        else:
            print('{0:.2f}'.format(d))
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Sample Input: `100,0,0,0,100,100,100`
Sample Output: `200.00`

TIA!

Comment: The error implies `min_Key` is not a key inside the dict `q`, but based on how it is assigned, it should be. Can you print the value of `q` and `min_Key` before the `del` call to check?

Comment: I tried. I was assuming `min_Key` to be the position of the dict as the program prints the value of `min_Key` as some integers but I realized that dictionary in Python3.6 has no order for Keys.

To solve this problem, can I use an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` library instead?

Comment: OH SORRY, I double checked again and I found out the `min_Key` is some integer and it is actually representing the Key of dict `q`.
My program works for the sample input but when I submitted to **Automarker** to test the program, it didn't pass 3 cases. The only clue for the possible inputs on **Automarker** is that they test the program using large data.

Comment: Here is another sample input: `200,25,25,10,1,50,25,140,30`
The output should be: `115.14`

Comment: Since you figured it out, you can add an answer with what worked and mark that as accepted. It would help others who might have the same issue in the future.

Comment: I wish if I can do that but it's the school assignment,
I can't really post the correct answer online. I'm sorry.
Thank you again!

Comment: You don't need to post the entire homework code. Just a brief description of the error, and how you resolved it. You should be able to make a random sample snippet that replicates the error right? That way you won't be posting a solution to your homework